# Best way to architecture server side i18n

Tags: nestjs

I'm using nestjs to create my REST API, and I got the requirement to support i18n for all the messages that the API returns (exception messages, hints, and so on) and I'm wondering what is the better way to do it with nestjs framework.

With plain express, I can get the user language from the request headers, and that can be translated to a Nestjs Middleware in order to put the language code into someware that lives in the request execution context and then using from my i18n service (I do not want to add language parameters everyware I need the user language) What do you think? Is it a propper architecture to resolve my requirement? Which is the best place to put the language for the current request?

Comment: This blog post may be of some inspiration regarding server side i18n: https://dev.to/adrai/how-does-server-side-internationalization-i18n-look-like-5f4c

Answer (score 8):

I'd use **i18-node** package https://github.com/mashpie/i18n-node, is compatible with express, and therefore there are no contradictions to use it with Nest as well. Also, I'd recommend registering a custom decorator as a wrapper around `res.__` call.

Comment: Thank you Kamil. What I wonder is how to use i18n for example in my services. Think about throwing a business logic exception from a service, including a friendly error message that have to be in the user prefered language.

Comment: @JoseSelesan `a friendly error message that have to be in the user prefered language` - API stands for a programming interface intended for programmers, not for (end) users. So it probably should not be in a programmers spoken language but in a standard spoken language used among all programming languages which is English :) I mean if e.g. JS uses English for its language constructs why API internals should speak a different language. Just a discussion point to think on.

Answer (score 4):

I've been using [Nestjs-i18n](https://github.com/ToonvanStrijp/nestjs-i18n) package.

It contains built-in features such as [I18nService](https://github.com/ToonvanStrijp/nestjs-i18n#i18nlang-decorator-and-i18nservice) and [I18nLang decorator](https://github.com/ToonvanStrijp/nestjs-i18n#i18nlang-decorator-and-i18nservice).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to get the language code in a service without passing it as a parameter.
If you want to access the language code from your services, you will have to pass it as a parameter, or retrieve the language code associated to the user object from another place.

I handle translations in my app as following:

I have a Language decorator for handling the 'accept-language' header overriding by client:

```
export const Language = createRouteParamDecorator((data, req) => {
if (!req.body.lang) return req.getLocale();
return req.body.lang;
});
```

And use it like this in a controller:

```
@Post()
public async testLocale(@Req() req, @Language() locale) {
   return this.myService.someMethod(someParam, locale);
}
```

Comment: I use the `@Req() req` decorator and then in the controller method I set the i18n locale like this: `setLocale(getLocale(req));`

This allows to simply use `getLocale()` within services if needed. The localization will respect the set locale.

Comment: any reason we can't use global interceptor to set the locale ?

Answer (score 0):

To make an architectural decision you ask for I would think on the below first.

1. If your API wraps a service that only does some actions (sending emails, proceesses some data, makes calculations and the like) I would only return standardizes error or hint codes  and their standardized English messages.

   The translation thing should be done on a front-end application whatever it is. On its end you would be fine just using any templating engine (does not matter if it is even Node or PHP or anything else you create your front-end with) and [Poedit](https://poedit.net/).

   The application is responsible to know which error or hint code translates to which matching front-end UI message. And Poedit will take its work on translation with [node-gettext](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gettext) and [gettext-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gettext-parser).
2. If on the contrary your API wraps the multilanguage content (which is not your case as you describe it) than you have no choice and you have to implement the language selecting mechanism for each request. As you said the language is defined by the browser via HTTP request header.

   You have to create the application service object responsible for getting content translations (from the content repository) based on the language argument and, say, the base language content item ID you pass into it.

   FYI pay attention to `REQUEST` [scoped injection](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/injection-scopes) so the service is dependent on the particular request context and treat the language setting correctly.

The i18n implementation can be anything applicable to your case.