# Opinionated i18n for NestJS

Tags: node.js, localization, internationalization, nestjs

I'm currently working on a project which uses Angular/NestJS. We have implemented i18n in Angular using ngx-translate which is great, I'm wondering what is the best way to implement i18n in NestJS. I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48195353/best-way-to-architecture-server-side-i18n) but the only answer here is to use **i18-node** and then implement custom decorators, wrappers etc. around that to use it with Nest.

I'm wondering if there is some 'opinionated' way of implementing i18 in NestJS? Also if the 'best' way to do it is with i18-node, what decorators/wrappers should I likely build?

Comment: what exactly you wanna to translate?

Comment: Hi! mostly error/success messages and a few email constants (Not complete emails just translations for Enums, constants etc.)

Comment: then use https://www.npmjs.com/package/i18next with gettext plugin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've been using [Nestjs-i18n](https://github.com/ToonvanStrijp/nestjs-i18n) package.

It contains built-in features such as [I18nService](https://github.com/ToonvanStrijp/nestjs-i18n#i18nlang-decorator-and-i18nservice) and [I18nLang decorator](https://github.com/ToonvanStrijp/nestjs-i18n#i18nlang-decorator-and-i18nservice).

Comment: That's what I ended up using & it's working fine for me till now :)

Comment: I haven't found anything related to the plural and gender formats, are those formats supported with this package?

Comment: @ŽeljkoŠević I didn't understand your question. You have any sample?

Comment: I meant on something like this https://github.com/mashpie/i18n-node#i18n__mf, MessageFormat can handle plural and gender formats, so I made a dynamic module and switched to this package

Comment: @ŽeljkoŠević, nested translations feature can handle plural and gender formats